# Export OCaml dune test results to file

Tags: shell, ocaml, ocaml-dune

I have been attempting to do something like:

```
dune runtest > test.txt
```

However, whenever I attempt this an empty test.txt file is created. I would like for the output of dune runtest to be saved into test.txt, and ideally for the Terminal to not output anything (the output is only able to be viewed in the file). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`dune runtest` most likely writes to `stderr`, and `>` will only redirect `stdout`.

To only redirect `stderr`:

```
dune runtest 2> test.txt
```

To redirect both `stdout` and  `stderr`:

```
dune runtest > test.txt 2&>1
```

where `2&>1` means "redirect stderr to stdout".

Some shells also support this short-hand for the above:

```
dune runtest &> test.txt
```